# sum of the squares of the first 5 numbers using DEBUG - Assembly programming in DOSBOX

Tags: debugging, assembly, sum, x86-16, dosbox

Please help, I need the sum of the squares of the first 5 numbers using DEBUG - Assembly programming in DOSBOX. This an example of a 2^2:

```
  -a 100 </i> 
       15BC:0100 mov ax,1 
       15BC:0103 mov bx,2 ; Base Number 
       15BC:0106 mov cx,2 ; Exponent 
       15BC:0109 ;bucle 109: 
       15BC:0109 mov dx,0  
       15BC:010C mul bx 
       15BC:010E loop 109  
       15BC:0110 int 20  
       15BC:0112 
       -g 110
```

Comment: Well, how would you write that in a higher-level language? Surely you need an addition somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instruction `mul bx` multiplies the content of `ax` (always) with the content of the `bx` register (the parameter). Cause that are 16 bit registers, the result can have up to 32 bits. The lower 16 bits of this result are placed in `ax` and the higher 16 bits in `dx`. So you don't have to clear `dx` before `mul`. That's only necessary for `div`.

The code to calculate `ax = 3²` (in general `ax = bx`<sup>`cx`</sup>) would then be:

```
    mov  ax, 1
    mov  bx, 3  ; Base Number (that is multiplied by itself cx plus one times)
    mov  cx, 2  ; Exponent (how often the multiplication should be repeated)
expLoop:
    mul  bx
    loop expLoop
```

If only the square is to be calculated, the loop is no longer necessary and the code could be simplified:

```
    mov  ax, 3 ; Base Number (that is multiplied by itself one time)
    mul  ax
```

This will calculate `3²` (in general `ax²`). Note that `bx` and `cx` are not used here anymore.

As Michael already mentioned, you have to sum up your results after this if you want to get a sum of squares. Cause `cx` is not used anymore, it could be used with `loop` to iterate over all the numbers to be squared. `bx` could be used to store the sum of the squares:

```
    xor  bx, bx  ; Sum is initialised to zero
    mov  cx, 5   ; Iterate from 5 down to 1
iterate:
    mov  ax, cx
    mul  cx      ; Calculate the square of the acutal number
    add  bx, ax  ; Sum up the squares in bx
    loop iterate
```